# Why does Java compiler allow casting null to primitive type in ternary operator

Tags: java, compiler-errors, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, ternary-operator

This small program throws `NullPointerException` at the line of ternary operator:

```
public class Main {
    int someMethod() {
        return (true ? null : 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Main obj= new Main();
        obj.someMethod();
    }
}
```

I understand the reason is `null` cannot be casted to  `int`.

However, the question is why does Java compiler allow this kind of code passed, while something likes below will cause compile-time error:

```
int i = null; //Error: incompatible types: <nulltype> cannot be converted to int
```

Comment: Did you try running the first version of code (though it compiles)

Comment: Well if it's an error then it's not allowed. But anyway the code is not wrong.

Comment: @user7 yes, tried and it throw npe at run-time as described.

Comment: Because it's autoboxing, but the actual unbox operation doesn't take place until runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Java Language Specification - Conditional Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), Java will evaluate the conditional expression at **run-time**, not compile-time. That's why the error is not detected during compile-time:

> **At run time**, the first operand expression of the conditional expression is evaluated first. The resulting boolean value is then used to choose either the second or the third operand expression.

So in your case:

```
int someMethod() {
    return (true ? null : 0);
}
```

imaging `true` is a method containing complicated logic, and it makes sense if Java evaluate the 1st operand (in this case is `true`) at run-time. Then, based on the rule:

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

Since 3rd operand `0` is primitive type (T), the type of the expression would be T  type (`int`). So, unboxing a null reference to `int` will result in NPE.

Comment: Also, it's not strictly necessary to be of compatible types in all situations: `System.out.println (yourBool? "yes" : 3)` is valid and executes fine.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler disallows

```
int i = null;
```

because the type of the expression `null` is the "null type", and there is no unboxing conversion rule for the "null type". ([JLS section 5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)).

However, it is allowed to write:

```
int i = (Integer) null;
```

because the expression `(Integer) null` has type `java.lang.Integer` and will cause unboxing, which always results in a NullPointerException.

When you write:

```
return (true ? null : 0);
```

in a method that returns `int`, or simply when you write:

```
int i = (true ? null : 0);
```

it compiles. The type of `(true ? null : 0)` is `java.lang.Integer` and it becomes similar to `int i = (Integer) null;`

You should note that `null` can be "Boxed" as Integer, Float, Double etc. in the context of a ternary expression (`a ? b : c`). This is specifically described in [JLS 5.1.7 (boxing conversions)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and [JLS 15.25 (Conditional operator "? :")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).